# How to segment binary image based on concavity?

Tags: image, matlab, analysis

I have a binary image such as:

[image]

I am looking to separate the main big elliptical white section from the little mushroom cloud on top. This needs to be an automatic process for many different images, which may be quite different but will still have this characteristic of a main blob and a touching smaller blob either above or to the sides.

I was thinking of using watershed but it doesn't work in all cases depending on the proportions of the extra blob. I am now trying to see if there is a way of finding the edge of the binary image and putting a condition on the concavity of this edge but I cannot find how to do this.

Ideally implementation in MATLAB but if this can be done better in SciPy/Mathematica, that's fine as well.

Comment: Have a look at [Matlab Image Processing Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/image/index.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop).

Comment: If you have the Image Processing Toolbox available it should be easy to find the edges, since you've already got a good mask, just use edge(). http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html Before you can then go on about concavity you'll probably have to connect the points found by edge() using a structuring element. See http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/detecting-a-cell-using-image-segmentation.html. Interesting for you is probably only step 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my attempt. The code is rough, but it's a general idea of how you can use the boundary and signed curvature to find the two points that segment the "mushroom top" from the rest of the body, and then using the turn predicate to determine the points of interest.

```
clear; clc;

binary_img = imread('bin.jpg') > 100;

% Get boundaries
b = bwboundaries(binary_img);

% Get largest boundary
b = b{cellfun(@length,b) == max(cellfun(@length,b))};

% Filter boundary - use circular convolution
b(:,1) = cconv(b(:,1),fspecial('gaussian',[1 81],40)',size(b,1));
b(:,2) = cconv(b(:,2),fspecial('gaussian',[1 81],40)',size(b,1));

% Find curvature
curv_vec = zeros(length(b),1);
for i = 0:size(b,1)-1
    p_b = b(mod(i-25,length(b))+1,:); % p_b = point before
    p_m = b(mod(i,length(b))+1,:);    % p_m = point middle
    p_a = b(mod(i+25,length(b))+1,:); % p_a = point after

    dx_ds = p_a(1)-p_m(1);              % First derivative
    dy_ds = p_a(2)-p_m(2);              % First derivative
    ddx_ds = p_a(1)-2*p_m(1)+p_b(1);    % Second derivative
    ddy_ds = p_a(2)-2*p_m(2)+p_b(2);    % Second derivative
    curv_vec(i+1) = dx_ds*ddy_ds-dy_ds*ddx_ds;
end

% Find local maxima for curvature
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(curv_vec);
[pks,pks_idx] = sort(pks);

% Select two largest curvatures
p1_max = b(curv_vec == pks(end),:);
p2_max = b(curv_vec == pks(end-1),:);

% Paint biggest contiguous region
rp = regionprops(binary_img,'Area','PixelIdxList','PixelList');
rp = rp(max(vertcat(rp.Area)) == vertcat(rp.Area));

% Paint all points to the left of the line
img = zeros(size(binary_img));
img(rp.PixelIdxList) = 0.5;
for i = 1:length(rp.PixelList)     
    turn = sign(det([1 p1_max(1) p1_max(2);
                     1 p2_max(1) p2_max(2);
                     1 rp.PixelList(i,2) rp.PixelList(i,1);]));

    if (turn > 0) 
        img(rp.PixelList(i,2),rp.PixelList(i,1)) = 1;
    end
end

figure(1);
subplot(1,3,1);
plot(b(:,1), b(:,2),'o');
hold on;
plot(p1_max(1), p1_max(2),'ro','Markersize',5,'LineWidth', 5);
plot(p2_max(1), p2_max(2),'ro','Markersize',5,'LineWidth', 5);

subplot(1,3,2);
plot(curv_vec);

subplot(1,3,3);
imshow(img);
```

Using this image:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how you got those parameters for the circular convolution bit please?

Comment: @danm I got those parameters by trial and error. Basically, the gaussian blur must be strong enough to make all the ripples on the boundary smooth.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason you didn't use 'imgaussfilt' as recommended by Matlab instead: http://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html ?

Comment: In my defense, my version of Matlab (R2009a) doesn't actually support that function. But yea, that function is useful for preventing potential errors with using `fspecial`, especially using an even sized kernel by accident (which I've done before). But, there are two things with that function: 1) first of all it's made for 2D images and not specifically 1D arrays, so it actually doesn't fit the semantics as well and *might* not actually be as efficient as `cconv` 2) It is not `circular` by default. You will have to add this parameter yourself.

Answer (score 3):

You can use horizontal and vertical histograms to segment the *mushroom*. Note that the code is quite simple: image processing code is just 10-15 lines.

This approach has the advantage to be robust (in theory, you need to test it on your other images) when the mushroom blob is linked with the other smaller blobs, where simply keeping the largest blob or the longer contour could lead to errors.

Comments in code should clarify each step, but please comment if something is not clear.

```
close all; clear all;
img = imread('mushroom .jpg');

% Threshold
binary = img > 100;

% Apply open morphology operator to "enlarge" holes and remove small blobs
se = strel('disk',3);        
opened= imopen(binary, se);

% Compute vertical projection
projectionVer = sum(opened,1);

% Find max value on vertical projection
% Is basically the vertical simmetry axis of the mushroom
[~, centerX] = max(projectionVer);

% Find limits of the mushroom
% This procedure can be helpful if the central blob (the mushroom)
% is linked with the small left and right blobs.
% In this case simply taking the larget boundary, or the largest
% blob will fail. 
% But since you said "touching smaller blobs either above of to the
% sides"...

leftMin = min(projectionVer(1 : centerX));
rightMin = min(projectionVer(centerX+1 : end));
leftX = find(projectionVer(1 : centerX) == leftMin, 1, 'last');
rightX = find(projectionVer(centerX+1 : end) == rightMin, 1, 'first');
rightX = centerX + rightX;

% Crop the image to keep only the mushroom
mushroom = img(:, leftX : rightX);

% Compute horizontal projection on mushroom
projectionHor = sum(mushroom, 2);

% Find first minimum peak
[pks, loc] = findpeaks(- projectionHor);
minY = loc(1); % << You are looking for this!
minYVal = -pks(1);

% Segmentation
topY = find(projectionHor>0, 1);

result = uint8(opened);

% probably you can do better than for loops, but ok for now...
for y=leftX:rightX
    for x=topY:size(result ,1)
        if(opened(x,y))            
            if(x<=minY)
                %top
                result(x,y) = 127;
            else
                %bottom
                result(x,y) = 200;
            end
        end
    end
end

%Plotting

imshow(result);
figure();

subplot(221);
imshow(img);
title('Image');

subplot(222);
hold on;
plot(flip(projectionHor), (1 : length(projectionHor)));
plot(minYVal, size(img,1) - minY, 'or');
title('Horizontal Projection');
axis([0, +Inf, 0, size(img,1)]);
hold off;

subplot(223);
hold on;
plot(projectionVer);
plot(leftX, leftMin, 'or');
plot(rightX, rightMin, 'or');
title('Vertical Projection');
axis([0, size(img,2), 0, +Inf]);
hold off;

subplot(224);
imshow(img);
hold on;
plot((1:size(img,2)), ones(1,size(img,2))*minY, 'r'); 
plot(ones(1,size(img,1))*leftX, (1:size(img,1)), 'g');
plot(ones(1,size(img,1))*rightX, (1:size(img,1)), 'b');
title('Result');
hold off;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This technique assumes a certain degree of symmetry though that may make it a bit dangerous for other cases that may be less symmetric than this one.

Comment: @danm No, no symmetry assumed, that's the point. You just take the verical projection max value to be sure to be inside the mushroom, but it doesn't need to be symmetric. I used symmetry axis just to clarify, but in fact it turns out to be misleading

Comment: Yes, but taking the minimum peak of the horizontal projection _does_ rely on symmetry.

Comment: @danm ah yes, you're right, didn't thought of that. Btw, the other answer  of jucestain got immediately my +1, but also it won't work in specific cases. That's why in my opinion you should also clarify that in your question, and add other 1 or 2 "difficult" images (i,e at least with connected side blobs, and with no symmetry in the top). That will help us to find a better algorithm, and you'll receive a better answer. (If you still can't upload images, just put link and I'll edit for you)

Comment: Hmm, I think the approach jucestain used in terms of the curvature might be the right path to follow, although this obviously needs to be modified as taking the two largest curvatures clearly isn't going to work in all cases. To give you some context, these images are in fact from a genetic optimizer, which comes up with all sorts of weird and wonderful things! As the aim is to use the maximum value of the distance transform, some of these features don't really matter as they don't affect the final result. The whole problem is too complicated to explain here but I'll add an example or two.

Comment: Well, mine is just a proposal, don't pretend to be the best solution. I like the other answer. Probably it's a better start for you :D